# Should `System.IO.Path` be concrete?

Tags: .net

Members of the `Path` class like `Path.Combine` are indispensable. They lead to great, clean, correct code. Unfortunately, if you use it for something like managing header paths in a C++ preprocessor, you'll quickly realize that it's showing up more than expected in the profiler. Why?

> Exceptions: ArgumentException: *path1* or *path2* contain one or more of the invalid characters defined in  `GetInvalidPathChars`.

Even without the check, the combine command is O(n) (since it has to copy the string contents). However, that is much less expensive than checking for the existence of any of `GetInvalidPathChars`' ~40 members.

I believe that the `Path` class should be an immutable type that contains a string known to not contain any invalid characters. Static members should be provided for operating on `string` (as exists now) and an identical set added for working on `Path` objects. Making this change in the .NET Framework:

- Is not a breaking change (changing a static class to a sealed concrete type is non-breaking)
- Significantly improves performance of several best-practices operations

Opinions?

Answer (score 2):

The Uri class can provide that sort of functionality if you don't mind the file:// syntax. I think .Net prefers the use of the Uri class anyway since that can allow locating of resources other than just local files, although this does require extra work on the program side to support that.