# c# string Trim doesn't work, a weird problem

Tags: c#, string

I have string like that:

```
string val = 555*324-000
```

now, I need to remove * and - chars, so I use that code ([based on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx))

```
char[] CharsToDelete = {'*', '(', ')', '-', '[', ']', '{', '}' };
string result = val.Trim(CharsToDelete);
```

but the string remains the same. What's the reason ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329961/c-removing-common-invalid-characters-from-a-string-improve-this-algorithm/1330360#1330360 for a extensive discussion on how to remove a set of char from a string

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Trim ...Removes all **leading and trailing** occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String  object.
You should use Replace method instead.

Answer (score 6):

Because Trim() will remove any character in CharsToDelete at the beginning and at the end of the string.

You should use val.Replace() function.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be

```
string val = 555*324-000
char[] CharsToDelete = {'*', '(', ')', '-', '[', ']', '{', '}' };

foreach (char c in CharsToDelete)
{
  val = val.Replace(c, '');
}
```

Comment: -1: The two overloads of `Replace()` are `Replace(string, string)` and `Replace(char, char)`. Neither accept a char array.

Comment: Apologies... you are quite correct... i didnt fire up VS to check my mistake

Now fixed