# Get price of in-app product as a double

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

How can I get a price of a consumable product from c# code? I need this as a double, but the `StorePrice` object seems to only offer `FormattedPrice` as a string (e.g. "42,00 $"):

```
var storeProducts = await this.storeContext.GetStoreProductsAsync(new[] { "UnmanagedConsumable" }, new[] { "xyz" });
var iap = storeProducts.Products["xyz"];
var price = iap.Price;
price.FormattedPrice ...
```

I need to get the price as double so I can calculate how much cheaper one IAP is compared to the other.

It looks like I will have to parse the amount out of the formatted string, but that just feels stupid. Are there any other options?

Comment: Convert.ToDouble(priceString); ?

Comment: That throws FormatException. The string is Formatted - contains the currency symbol (e.g. "42,00 $").
I also tried decimal.Parse(xyz.Price.FormattedPrice, NumberStyles.Currency); and that also throws FormatException

Comment: do you have access to the source code?

Comment: [This SO question should help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3532923/463206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API which provides the price as a pure number. I think parsing the string is not the worst solution, you could use `NumberStyles.Currency` to make this easier:

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse(price.FormattedPrice, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

However you need to make sure you are actually parsing the string under the correct culture, so that the `Parse` method can deal with it. You should definitely also wrap this in an exception handler to have an alternate solution when the parsing fails.

The currency should match the user's current region setting. You can get this using `GlobalizationRegion`:

```
var geographicRegion = new Windows.Globalization.GeographicRegion();
var code = geographicRegion.CodeTwoLetter;
```

Comment: I tried that, but I am not sure which culture to use or whether it depends on windows locale.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think the `GeographicRegion` should match the currency

Comment: Turns out the Region api is not needed, getting culture via `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` works, BUT you first need to remove the `;nbsp` symbol from the formatted string (replace is with regular space), then parsing will work.
Accepting your answer

Comment: This is so sad, why does the API only return the formatted price and not the raw number...?